# How to send reply for TCP requests (spring-integration)?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

I would need something similar like in [Can not send response for UDP message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900627/can-not-send-response-for-udp-message)
but for TCP. So the client send message and TCP server can send back response like OK. For TCP socket-expression="@inbound.socket" and                        destination-expression="headers['ip_packetAddress']" cannot be used.

This is how my config look like now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
    xmlns:int-event="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd">

  <int:channel id="tcpSend"/>

  <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client" type="client"/>

  <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="server" type="server" host="localhost" port="1234"/>

  <int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="tcpOutbound" channel="tcpSend"
                                   connection-factory="client"/>

  <int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="tcpInbound" channel="tcpReceive"
                                  connection-factory="server"/>

  <int:service-activator id="tcpHandler" input-channel="tcpReceive" output-channel="tcpSend"
                         ref="listener"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of TCP it is much easier because you can use [Inbound Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-gateways).

The sample on the matter is in the official repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server